# Which test to use to test for heteroscedasticity in a non linear model/fit?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, heteroscedasticity, curve-fitting

I would like to test for heteroscedasticity in a non linear fit.
I have a explanatory vector `x` and an explained variable `y` and want to detect heteroscedasticity in the data. I have a linear fit and a non-linear fit model and corresponding residuals vectors `residual_linear_fit` and  `residual_non_linear_fit`. Standard test such as Breusch-Pagan require that the models be a ordinary linear regression model. Which test should I use to test for heteroscedasticity with non linear fitting. What should be the appropriate code?

[image]

Here is the code (in python) to generate data

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pdb
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x,a):
  return a+(1/(1+np.exp(-x) ))

def lin(x,a):
  return a*x

x = np.arange(0,10,.05)

print(len(x))
err = np.random.rand(1,len(x))/4
y = sigmoid(x,1) + err[0]

plt.plot(x,y, ".")

popt_lin, pcov_lin = curve_fit(lin, x, y)
residuals_lin = y-lin(x, *popt_lin)
plt.plot(x, lin(x, *popt_lin), 'k-',)
#
popt_sigmoid, pcov_sigmoid = curve_fit(sigmoid, x, y)
residuals_sigmoid = y-sigmoid(x, *popt_sigmoid)
plt.plot(x, sigmoid(x, *popt_sigmoid), 'r-',)

plt.show()
```